# js: Add style to element by "id"

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

I have this real code:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
$('#main-header').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
}
</script>
```

In this page: http://temporal-1.d246.dinaserver.com/

I just need to change the background color of the element:

```
<header id="main-header" .... </header>
```

But, as you can see, it is not working.
What's the problem?

Comment: have you debugged to see if the scrolltop is equal to 0 to get inside the if statement?

Comment: why not just use `document.getElementById("main-header").style.background-color = "red";`?

Comment: May be you need to check after complete page load only you have to write this script . Move this script tag at end of <body> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1] Use "jQuery" instead of "$"

2] Put quotes around your selector (as you have it in example above, but not on site)

Comment: the JS code in @damitj07 's answer will run slightly faster as it doesnt use jquery. it is also a cleaner and more correct code sample to use

Answer (score 6):

When I perform Scroll down action on your site. Following error is printed on the console :

```
(index):200 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

For the statement below :

```
$(header#main-header).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Now when I tried doing this using just JS it works fine. Just open the console and try it out.

```
document.getElementById("main-header").setAttribute("style","background-color:red");
```

Comment: or also `.style.background-color: "red";`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon That should be `element.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a hash: `$('#main-header').css({'background-color': 'red'})`;

Comment: the JS answer is a better solution to use

Answer (score 0):

After opening your URL which you have mentioned as your page(http://temporal-1.d246.dinaserver.com/) - I tried in console with below code, it worked!

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
        jQuery('#main-header').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: whoever given downvote, please provide reason!

Open the page which was mentioned and try the above code which I have given, it will work!

Comment: comments like these should not be added

Comment: then how can I come to know what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: the JS answer is a better solution to use which is why yours probably got downvoted